# Reference an object from within the object

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I am making a menu structure. It goes as follows: there is a menu class which has a label, a list of tuples which are its items and a 'previous menu'.

So my idea is that when in Main, previous will be None. The items in the menus are either functions or another menu. (A function can also be something that generates a menu) When you then select option 1 I want to set the 'previous' parameter in the option_1_menu to main_menu

class Menu:

```
def __init__(self, label, options):
    self.label = label
    self.options = options
    self.previous = None

def set_previous(self,previous_menu):
    self.previous = previous_menu

def evaluate(self, choice):
    if isinstance(self.options[int(choice) - 1][1],Menu):
        print('this is a menu')
        # Set the previous menu to this menu
        self.options[int(choice) - 1][1].set_previous(self)
        # Return the new menu
        return self.options[int(choice) - 1][1]
        # t_current_menu(self.options[int(choice) - 1][1])
    else:
        print('This is a function')
        self.options[int(choice) - 1][1]()
```

So my question is about the line where I set the previous menu to this menu. I basically set the 'previous' one to the one I am currently in. Can I reference to self in that way I do there to accomplish this?

Note: the 'this is a function' part is still very much WiP

Comment: Yes, you can reference to it that way. Moreover, you can be sure by writing an unit test and running it. Object identity in checked by `is` operator. So just create Menu with single option (another menu), `evaluate` it and check if `subMenu.previous is prevMenu`.

Comment: Thanks :)

And yes I know Unit Testing. I am a bit unsure about that when it comes to how to actually test stuff that relies on outside things. But that's another problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, `self` is a perfectly valid "reference to a `Menu` instance" so there is no problem calling `someothermenu.set_previous(self)`.  Adding a unit test as @Nsh suggests is also never a bad idea (for this or *any* other functionality:-).